# Insert>Equation does not recognise LaTeX "shortcuts" as per Google Docs help guide

Tags: google-docs, latex

In Google Docs, when I choose from the menu Insert>Equation, it displays literally shortcuts such as "\frac". For example, the following:

> \frac {a}{b}

Should display a fraction with a over b. But it just shows the text above. What am I doing wrong? I have followed the usage defined and demonstrated  here:

- [Google docs help - Insert and use equations in a document](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160749?hl=en)
- [HostMath Equation editor](http://www.hostmath.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite mimicking some of the LaTeX syntax, Google Document Equation Editor is still WYSIWYG: changes to an equation happen immediately in response to key presses, there is no compilation stage. In particular, there are no `{ }` for grouping: you control the placement of characters visually.  Think of entering "\frac " as equivalent to clicking a button for "fraction pattern" in the toolbar.

To enter a fraction of the form a/b, type

> \frac a<kbd>Tab</kbd>b<kbd>Tab</kbd>

The fraction structure appears first, with the cursor set in the numerator. After entering "a" there,pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>
moves the cursor to the denominator. The second <kbd>Tab</kbd> moves it out of the denominator, so you can continue with the formula.

Instead of Tab, the right arrow key may be used.